# RuntimeError: qtutils is only compatible with version 2 of the PyQt4

Tags: python-2.7, qt4, qtcore

The program that I am trying to run is importing the following packages in an anaconda environment:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

I installed PyQt4 by following the instructions in [this link](https://github.com/jnicoleoliveira/SPECData/issues/6)

However, I am getting the following error after installing:

```
RuntimeError: qtutils is only compatible with version 2 of the  PyQt4 API.Whilst you can import PyQt4 prior to importing qtutils (in order to tell qtutils to use PyQt4), either set the API version to 2 yourself, or import qtutils (which will set it for you) prior to importing QtGui or QtCore.
```

The program is trying to import

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from qtutils import inmain_later,inthread,inmain
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what program are (were) you using that uses qtutils? I develop qtutils and am curious if anything is using it outside of what we made it for.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, import PyQt4 after importing qtutils.

Qtutils sets the PyQt4 sip API to version 2, which must be done before importing PyQt4.